# $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{(m+n)/2- 1} e^{-x(\frac{mz+n}{2})} dx $ (density of $F$ distribution)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gamma-function

I'm deriving the density of the $F_{n, m}$ distribution and I ended up with the following integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{(m+n)/2- 1} e^{-x(\frac{mz+n}{2})} dx
$$

This integral looks like it could be molded into a Gamma function but I don't see how. I can add the entire context to this question but I don't think it would help.

Comment: Peform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $t=x\left( {\frac{{mz + n}}{2}} \right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Mellin transform of $e^{-a x}$
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-\alpha x} \; dx = \alpha^{-s}\Gamma(s)
$$
now set $s = (m+n)/2$ and $\alpha = (m z + n)/2$